# Appending integers to an empty list, then printing those integers (Tic-Tac-Toe)

Tags: python, list, append, tic-tac-toe

I'm very new to Python (started taking an Udemy course last month and wrote my first line of Python code then), so I am hoping someone can offer *merciful* advice on an aspect of an interactive tic-tac-toe project I'm developing. Note: This is a two-player game in which two players would use the same computer.

**The problem:**

I'm trying to write a function that will take in user input in range 1-9 inclusive ("position"), store that input as an integer in an empty list called "board," then replace the position with a variable called "marker" ('X' or 'O').

**My code:**

```
# POSITION IS SUPPOSED TO BE AN INT THAT IS STORED IN A LIST CALLED "BOARD"

board = [''] * 9
marker = ''
position = ''

def place_marker(board, marker, position):


# while our position is an acceptable value
    while position not in range(1,9+1):
        position = int(input("Choose a number from 1 through 9: " ))   
        board.append(position)

    print(board)

# NOW HOW DO I MAKE SURE THAT THE POSITION CORRESPONDS WITH EACH MARKER?
```

**Failed solution attempts:**

I've sort of lost track of my failed solution attempts, but here is one of them:

```
board = [''] * 9
marker = ''
position = ''

def place_marker(board, marker, position):


# while our position is an acceptable value
    while position not in range(1,9+1):
        position = int(input("Choose a number from 1 through 9: " ))   
        board.append(position)

# at the board's position, place marker 'X' or 'O'
    board[position] = marker
    print(board)
```

This resulted in:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-197-76194c5efcbd> in <module>
----> 1 board[position]

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Maybe I'm trying to do too much at a time. I've tried referring to the documentation as well as other resources like W3Schools and Real Python, but I can't seem to figure out the solution for the life of me. If someone could just point out where I've fallen short or gone wrong, or give me a clue or two in the right direction, I'd be super grateful.

Comment: `board.append(position)` should not be inside the `while` loop.

Comment: You shouldn't be appending anything to `board`.

Comment: `board` is not an empty list, you filled it with: `board = [''] * 9`

Comment: `position` shouldn't be a function parameter if you're assigning it in the function.

Comment: List indices start at 0, not 1.

Comment: You shouldn't use the same list to hold all the inputs and the board.

Comment: I don't think that traceback is coming from any of the lines that you posted.

Comment: When you assign `position` inside the function, it has no effect on the global variable with the same name. So if you try to access `board[position]` outside the function, that's `board['']`, and the empty string is not a valid index for the list.

Comment: Thank you, @Barmar. I really appreciate your responses. It's clear that there are a handful of issues with my code, so I will think on them and modify my approach.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure my answer is exactly what you want, but you may do something like this:

```
board = ['']*9
marker = "X"
position=0

def place_marker(board, marker, position):


# while our position is an acceptable value
    while position not in range(1,9+1):
        position = int(input("Choose a number from 1 through 9: " ))   
        #board.append(position-1)

# at the board's position, place marker 'X' or 'O'
    board[position-1] = marker
    print(board)
    
place_marker(board, marker, 4)
```

The position should be set as an integer. The index of board[] starts at 0, so the position you input should -1 to indicate the position in board[].

Output:

```
['', '', '', 'X', '', '', '', '', '']
```

Comment: Thank you, @AustinHe. I really appreciate your response. Took me some time to understand why this code works, admittedly, but here's what I understand: Because list indexing begins at 0, we must -1 from the input to ensure that the board only contains the actual range of values we want 1-9. I'll think on this along with the points made by the other commenter and work through this problem again on my own.

Answer (score 0):

When you work with a game like this I would suggest having the board as a list of integers. This will make it much easier to code and you will make less mistakes going back and forth between variable types. To easily switch turn you can use -1 as X, 1 as O, and 0 as empty spaces, this will make checking for empty slots super easy as well.

**Get user input**:

```
board = [0]*9  # Init board
print_board(board)  # Print board at start of game
user_turn = True  # User goes first

# Game loop
while 1:

# User turn to move
    if user_turn:

        # Loop until we get a valid input from user
        while 1:

            # Get user input from the console
            user_input = input('\nPlease enter your move (1-9): ')

            # Check if user input is a number
            if user_input.isnumeric():

                # If it is a number, make the string is an integer and subtract 1 since array indices starts at 0
                user_input = int(user_input) - 1

                # Check if the input - 1 is in range 0-8
                if user_input in range(9):

                    # Check if the input is an empty square
                    if board[user_input] == 0:

                        # If all conditions are true: Make the move on the board, print the new board and change turn
                        board[user_input] = -1
                        print_board(board)
                        user_turn = not user_turn
                        break
```

**Print the board**

This is where you convert your integer board to X, O and empty spots. It can be done by this short function.

```
def print_board(board):
    temp_board = [' ' if i == 0 else 'X' if i == -1 else 'O' if i == 1 else i for i in board]
    for row in range(3):
        print(f'\n{temp_board [row*3:3+row*3]}' if row == 0 else temp_board [row*3:3+row*3])
```

You convert it into string elements and then print it on different lines.

**Check for winners and full board**

You could first define all the winning lines:

```
winning_lines = ([0, 1, 2], [3, 4, 5], [6, 7, 8],  # Horizontally
             [0, 3, 6], [1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8],  # Vertically
             [0, 4, 8], [2, 4, 6])  # Diagonally
```

Then you check for a win by comparing input board and player turn to see if it matches the winning lines.

```
def is_winner(board, player):
    for pos in winning_lines:
        if board[pos[0]] == board[pos[1]] == board[pos[2]] == player:
            return 1
```

Checking to see if board is full is even easier:

```
def is_board_full(board):
    return 0 if 0 in board else 1
```

**Ending comments**

When you switch turn in your game loop you also need to check for win or board is full to see if you should end the loop, and possibly ask the player to play again. You could also add an AI player after you change turn and for example let it play with the Negamax algorithm.

If you want the full code you can check my [Tic-Tac-Toe repository](https://github.com/eligolf/tic_tac_toe_python). There are several versions including both Player vs Player (pvp) and Player vs Environment/AI (pve), you can check both the commented ones and the compressed ones for some inspiration. Please let me know if you have any questions :)

Comment: Hi @eligolf — thank you **so** much for answering my question, with such thorough step-by-step examples! Days after my OP, I ended up scrapping the original and broke the problem down [into these smaller steps instead](https://imgur.com/a/BIxGP6F). However, I still can't figure out how to write/modify the code so that a user can only place a marker (represented here with the placeholder '$') if there is an empty space on the board.

Comment: Your approach in the first step (getting user input) is extremely succinct, but rather than copy what you wrote, I will see if I can derive the same result using my own code and use yours as a resource/for comparison. If there is one thing from your code I don't understand, it's how Python accepts "while 1" as the game loop and "while 1" as the user input loop. Could you explain that more? Thanks a ton for including your Tic-Tac-Toe repository, by the way! Very cool. @eligolf

Comment: In the code comments on my first input part you see how to control the user to only place on empty squares. In the image you sent it seems like you are trying to get both user 1 and user 2 input at the same time without putting the marker on the board, why? You need to get user 1 input, check if its valid, if so put it on board, and then change turn and repeat for user 2.

Comment: while 1 in Python just means that the loop will go on until you break. For clarity you could assign a bool while_playing for the first loop, and while_user_1 for the 2nd loop and then you change those bools to False when you want to break. The result would be the same.