# Function that will identify an empty string in a list and print a marker/symbol there (Python Tic-Tac-Toe)

Tags: python, string, list, function, conditional-statements

Coding newbie here, working on my first tic-tac-toe board in Python.

Recently, I asked [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66896124/appending-integers-to-an-empty-list-then-printing-those-integers-tic-tac-toe/66896712#66896712), and those who responded were very helpful. Beyond the fact that my code was incorrect/wasn't written in a way that could return the results I wanted, I realized I was getting ahead of myself. I needed to first write a function that would ask the two players (using 1 computer) in my tic-tac-toe game to take a turn, [which I successfully completed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EoWss.png). I then realized I needed to identify if there is a free space on my tic-tac-toe board to place a marker ('X' or 'O'), which I expressed as:

```
def space_check(board, position):
    
    return board[position] == ' '


space_check(test_board, 8)
```

**The problem:**

Now, I am having a really hard time with writing a function that will identify that a particular position on the board is free and then place the player's marker ('X' or 'O') in the empty space.

**Attempted solutions (note: these boards below are test boards, and I used '$' as a test marker):**

```
board = ['#','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h',' ']
marker = "$"
position=0

def place_marker(board, marker, position):


# while our position is an acceptable value (an int between 1 and 9)
    while position not in range(0,10):
        position = int(input("Choose a number from 1 through 9: " ))   
        

# at the board's position, place marker 'X' or 'O'
    board[position] = marker
    print(board)

place_marker(board, marker, position)
```

While this does return an output in the form of a list, when I display the board, the board is unaffected:

```
place_marker(board, marker, position)
display_board(board)
```

output:

```
 | |  
g|$|$
 | |  
______
 | |  
d|e|f
 | |  
______
 | |  
a|$|c
 | |
```

I also tried this, but the code won't run in VSC (the primary IDE I'm using for this project), even though it works in Jupyter notebook:

```
test_board = ['#','a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h',' ']

def player_choice(board):

    position = 0
    
    while position not in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] or not space_check(board, position):
        position = int(input("Choose your next position (1-9): " ))
        
    return position

player_choice(test_board)
```

output:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-169-72130d7eb126> in <module>
----> 1 player_choice(test_board)

<ipython-input-168-37d67e2d2b88> in player_choice(board)
      7 
      8     while position not in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] or not space_check(board, position):
----> 9         position = int(input("Choose your next position (1-9): " ))
     10 
     11     return position

ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''
```

I know there's a gap in my understanding here, but I don't know what I'm missing or how to proceed. Been stuck here for a few days now, so I'd appreciate the help!

**UPDATE: SOLUTION**

```
 # NEXT STEP: write a function that can check for input in acceptable range AND check for free space

def player_choice(board):

# while player is taking a turn
while True:
    try:
        # ask player for input
        position = int(input("Choose a Number (1 -9): " ))
        
        assert 0 < position < 10 # ensure that this input is within range
        assert board[position] == ' ' # ensure that there is a free space on which to place the input as marker
    
    except ValueError: # override the ValueError exception

        print("You didn't enter a number. Try again!") # tell player that input was not in range
        
    except AssertionError as e:
        print(e)

    else:
        return position
```

Comment: The exception is due to invalid typecasting of data type to int. Maybe you are entering data beyond numbers. You should use `try except` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first glance, it looks like taking `int(input()` for your position variable will cause errors if it is an empty string (`''`), which is the error you are getting. Instead, try this:

```
position = input("Choose Position (1-9):   ")
try:
    position = int(position) # Trying to make position into an integer
except: # If there is an error, 
    if position == '':
        # Do whatever if position is empty
    else: # This means the position is not an integer, and not an empty string
        # Do something to force the player to enter an integer or an empty string
```

We don't have enough code to try this on our own, so I'll just try and help from here :)

**Update**

```
marker = '$'
while True:
    try:
        position = int(input('Choose a Number (1 -9)   '))
        break
    except ValueError:
        if not position:  # 'not' compares to an emptry value, or a False boolean.
                          # It's much clearer imo than == ''
            position = marker
        pass
```

In response to your third comment, the `NoneType` Exception is when you have a `None` value when another value (string or integer) is expected. When you get an error, you can always google what the error means. Another thing that is good to develop when programming is to remember what some of the basic errors are, such as `NoneType` and `parsing error`. In your case, the Type Error `NoneType` means that you have a `None` value inside of your list.

Comment: Hi there! Thank you for answering! 

I haven't encountered try/except before this point (the online course I'm taking discusses it later), so I did a little research to understand what exceptions are and how to use try/except. Still, I'm not sure I understand how to get the code to do what I want. In other words, when I run the exact code you used, with the addition of an "else" parameter (using "parameter" colloquially, not in the Pythonic sense meaning "argument"), my board still doesn't update with the new marker. On the bright side, this did prompt my input function to actually run.

Comment: [Here's what happened](https://imgur.com/a/7CrNXGI) when I ran my first function using try/except: 

The code runs, but my board doesn't change (as you'll see from the output). What might I be doing wrong? Thank you in advance for working with me on this. I am really trying to understand!!

Comment: @cybersuccubus, check the update. What I think is happening, is that the position is where you want to place the marker, and since the user didn't enter a valid position, you have nowhere to place the marker. My update is just a cleaner version of what you wrote, and it makes sure that if your user can't enter an invalid position (in your code, they can enter an invalid position once and then another invalid and it will go through)

Comment: Deleted my last comment due to a critical typo. Thank you for this update! From what I've learned about try/except, I know this now places me closer to overcoming this road bump. However, it brings up another problem: earlier in my code, I have the following function:  `def place_marker(board, marker, position):
# at the board's position, place marker 'X' or 'O'
    board[position] = marker`  Now, after running the updated code, [I'm seeing this Type error](https://imgur.com/a/d2xpryc) in response to **def place_marker**.

Comment: Meant to tag you, @Dugbug

Comment: Thank you for all of your help, @Dugbug! Finally figured this one out and it is largely due to your help. Can't thank you enough!