# Gameplay not working in Python Tic-Tac-Toe game

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I have been [working on a Python tic-tac-toe game](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66943132/function-that-will-identify-an-empty-string-in-a-list-and-print-a-marker-symbol/66943238?noredirect=1#comment118474212_66943238) for about a month, and the end is finally in sight. I am struggling with the code for the gameplay and would really appreciate advice anyone might have for overcoming this obstacle.

**The problem:**

An iteration of my game_board reprints every time a player makes a move. As a result, the game ends before any single board has been filled.

**The code**

Here's the code for my game board:

```
game_board = ['#'] + ([' ']*9)
display_board(game_board)
```

Here is the code for my gameplay:

```
print('Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!')

# turn = '' # needs to be an empty string because we're storing the result of go_first(), a string, inside

while True: # loop forever
game_board = [' ']*10 # clear board 
player1_marker , player2_marker = assign_marker() # assign players to marker
turn = go_first() # randomly choose who goes first
print(f"{turn}, you're up first!")
play_game = input("Ready? Enter Yes or No.")

if play_game.lower()[0] == 'y': 
    game_on = True
else:
    game_on = False

while game_on: # initiates the start of the game

    if turn == 'Player 1': # if player 1 is first
        position = player_choice(game_board) # ask for position from player
        place_marker(game_board, player1_marker, position) # place marker at the position
        display_board(game_board) # display board

        if check_winner(game_board, player1_marker): # if there are no more moves
            game_on = False
            print(f"{turn} wins!")

        else: # if there's no winner
            if is_board_full(game_board): # check to see if the board is full
                # if board is full but there's no winner, it's a draw
                print("It's a draw!")
                break

            else: # if the board is NOT full ...
                turn = 'Player 2' #move on to player 2; THIS IS HOW TO ALTERNATE TURNS

    else: # if player 2 is first
        position = player_choice(game_board) # ask for position from player
        place_marker(game_board, player2_marker, position) # place marker at the position
        display_board(game_board)

        if check_winner(game_board, player2_marker):
            game_on = False
            print(f"{turn} wins!")

        else: # if there's no winner
            if is_board_full(game_board): # check to see if the board is full
                # if board is full but there's no winner, it's a draw
                game_on = False
                print("It's a draw!")
                break

            else: # if the board is NOT full ...
                turn = 'Player 1' #move on to player 2; THIS IS HOW TO ALTERNATE TURNS

if not replay():
    break
```

**The result**

```
Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!
Player 1 has chosen X
Player 2 is O
Player 1, you're up first!

 | |
 | | 
_____
 | |
 | | 
_____
 | |
 | |X
 | |
 | | 
_____
 | |
 |O| 
_____
 | |
 | |X
 | |
X| | 
_____
 | |
 |O| 
_____
 | |
 | |X
 | |
X|O| 
_____
 | |
 |O| 
_____
 | |
 | |X
 | |
X|O|X
_____
 | |
 |O| 
_____
 | |
 | |X
 | |
X|O|X
_____
 | |
 |O| 
_____
 | |
 |O|X

Player 2 wins!
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-36-9859c5aad566> in <module>
     54                     turn = 'Player 1' #move on to player 2; THIS IS HOW TO ALTERNATE TURNS
     55 
---> 56     if not replay():
     57         break

<ipython-input-30-73127fbca36c> in replay()
      9         choice = input("Do you want to play again? ") # program will keep asking for valid input
     10 
---> 11         if choice.lower()[0] == 'n':
     12             print("GAME OVER.")
     13             return False

IndexError: string index out of range
```

And, as this pertains to the IndexError:

```
def replay():

choice = ' '
# declare variable, which is an empty string

while choice.lower()[0] != 'y': #uppercasing the 'Y' ensures that input can only be uppercase
# while loop ensures any other input will be rejected

    choice = input("Do you want to play again? ") # program will keep asking for valid input

    if choice.lower()[0] == 'n':
        print("GAME OVER.")
        return False

else:
    print("LET'S PLAY!")
    return True
    # if player wants a replay, return a boolean True
```

**Any guesses as to why my code isn't working?**

I'm hoping this is enough code to inform any responses one might have. I'd be happy to share more of the code.

Also, I understand if some might feel like StackOverflow isn't the place for questions like this. I'm just trying to learn and figure things out! Thanks in advance!

Comment: How about checking whether `choice > 0`? Like so `if len(choice) < 1: choice = ' '; continue` directly after the `input`? Then it will ask again if choice is empty.

Comment: Thank you for answering, @wuerfelfreak! Although this solution did not work for me, I managed to figure this one out on my own.

Answer (score 1):

**I resolved this one and finally completed the game!! Here's what worked for me. I hope these solutions help someone else!**

1. I added print('\n'*50) to my **def display_board(board)** function (not shown above) so that when my board reprints—which is what it's apparently supposed to do—my reprinted boards aren't all on top of each other.
2. Also not shown in my code above, I realized that in my function for checking for a winner **def check_winner**, the original arguments were "board" and "marker" and I was returning **board[position] == marker**. This function should have instead taken in the arguments "board" and **"MARK"** and returned **board[position] == MARK**

**After I made these changes, I noticed there was a delay in the time it took my board to print out, a bug that I had encountered early on in developing this project. To fix that, I made the following changes:**

1. Within the **game_on** while loop (shown above), I reorganized the order of actions that should happen if turn == 'Player 1' or 'Player 2'. Rather than order my actions as (1) position = player_choice(game_board), (2) place_marker(game_board, player1_marker, position), and (3) display_board(game_board), I reordered them as: (1) display_board(game_board), (2) position = player_choice(game_board), and (3) place_marker(game_board, player1_marker, position).
2. Under **if check_winner**, I ensured that display_board(game_board) was the first actionable item.

**See the final gameplay code below:**

```
print('Welcome to Tic Tac Toe!')

# turn = '' # needs to be an empty string because we're storing the result of go_first(), a string, inside

while True: # loop forever
    game_board = [' ']*10 # clear board 
    player1_marker , player2_marker = assign_marker() # assign players to marker
    turn = go_first() # randomly choose who goes first
    print(f"{turn}, you're up first!")
    play_game = input("Ready? Enter Yes or No.")
    
    if play_game.lower()[0] == 'y': 
        game_on = True
        print("LET'S PLAY!")
    else:
        game_on = False

while game_on: # initiates the start of the game
    if turn == 'Player 1': # if player 1 is first

        display_board(game_board) # display board
        position = player_choice(game_board) # ask for position from player
        place_marker(game_board, player1_marker, position) # place marker at the position

        if check_winner(game_board, player1_marker): # if there are no more moves
            display_board(game_board) # display board
            print(f"{turn} wins!")
            game_on = False
        else: # if there's no winner
            if is_board_full(game_board): # check to see if the board is full
                # if board is full but there's no winner, it's a draw
                display_board(game_board) # display board
                print("It's a draw!")
                break
            else: # if the board is NOT full ...
                turn = 'Player 2' #move on to player 2; THIS IS HOW TO ALTERNATE TURNS

    else: # Player 2's turn
        display_board(game_board)
        position = player_choice(game_board) # ask for position from player
        place_marker(game_board, player2_marker, position) # place marker at the position

        if check_winner(game_board, player2_marker):
            display_board(game_board) # display board
            print(f"{turn} wins!")
            game_on = False
        else: # if there's no winner
            if is_board_full(game_board): # check to see if the board is full
                # if board is full but there's no winner, it's a draw
                display_board(game_board) # display board
                print("It's a draw!")
                break

            else: # if the board is NOT full ...
                turn = 'Player 1' #move on to player 1; THIS IS HOW TO ALTERNATE TURNS

if not replay():
    break
```